# Is there an option to make automator ask for specific password to proceed

Tags: shell, applescript, automator

I have an automator workflow, that I want to make unworkable without specific password: is there an option to do it?

I've tried to use "Ask for text" action, but there is no option to specify request text.
I think there is an option to make it work with AppleScript or shell someway.

Comment: Do you just need to ask for a password or do you also need to elevate the rights?

Comment: I just need for ask a password.